# find out if a payable app is installed the very very first time

Tags: android, google-analytics, usage-statistics

I try to figure out if someone actually installs the app the very first time ever. The User has probably more then one device, so I try to figure out, if an install is after an already install or the very very first time. (sorry for my probably bad english explanation)

I am selling my app and I do not understand the statistics in Google Analytics or in the statistics in the Google Developer Console.

According to my Google Statistics there are a lot more installs then I see in my sells. Of course Users will probably purchase a new device and install the app again so I get a new installevent in the Google Analytics.

More details:
My app needs to install some content at very first time, which are loaded from a website. So this is my indicator, that the app is installed the first time on the device and I send an Event to Google Analytics. If a user would uninstall the app and reinstall, my app detects, that this is not the first time, because the content is already downloaded. This works fine on one device.

Question : how can I detect the amount of very very first installs of my app per day ? Or how can I detect in my app itself, if this is the very very first time install of the user.

**Update** regarding suggested solution:

Thanks, I read about the Unique User Id tracking, but I am not sure if this helps in my case.

There is the note:

"Note: Cross-device reports are only available for date ranges shorter than 90 days."

This will probably not covered my requirement. I try to explain my requirement with a sample:
1. User bought an app in June 2014
2. User buys a new device today and installs the app again on June 2015

When I would do a report in Google Analytics only from June 2015: Would the User, which installed the app on his new device be reported or not ? 
My requirement : It should not be reported as new user. Also Users from 2012 should not be reported, if they install the app again.

And another question. If I would implement this solution now (June 2015). Will the analytics be backward compatible, so a User which already has installed the app on older device installs now will not be reported as a new user ?

Answer (score 0):

Check for the Google analytics User ID View feature which will do the exact requirement you want. It will help you get the unique installs based on user and not on app install on devices.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/user-id

let me know if you need any further assistance to implement this.

Comment: Hi Nikunj. Thanks for helping. I studied your link. It sounds interresting and is good to know. I am not sure if it helps in my case. Could you please read my update in the question and have your thoughts ? (Sorry for the bad englisch)

Comment: If you have an unique User-Id in your app such as email or username which you can use as user-id in analytics then yes its still possible to consider all the old apps installs cover into single installs. But the new update of the app will determine this  so you have to send the update of the app, if user never install the new update of your app with the user-id implementation then it will not able to count in unless he update the app.

So all your install will be count as single based on which username or email the device owner is using with no matter how many device he owns.